# Javers changes to properties of set members appear as new objects

Tags: java, collections, javers

The following test fails

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    Javers javers = javers().build();
    Model anObject = new Model();
    Model anotherObject = new Model();

    Aggregate container = new AggregateHashSet();
    container.getInnerModels().add(anObject);
    container.getInnerModels().add(anotherObject);

    Commit firstCommit = javers.commit("author", container);
    log.info(firstCommit);

    anObject.setProperty("bob");
    anotherObject.setProperty("bob");

    Commit secondCommit = javers.commit("anotherAuthor", container);
    log.info(secondCommit);

    List<Change> changes = secondCommit.getChanges();
    List<Object> afftectedObjects = 

   changes.stream()
     .map(Change::getAffectedObject)
     .map(Optional::get).collect(toList());
   assertThat(afftectedObjects, containsInAnyOrder(anObject, anotherObject));
  }
```

Nothing special about the classes used as models and container

```
  static class Model {

     private String property;


     public String getProperty() {
       return property;
     }


     public void setProperty(String property) {
       this.property = property;
     }
   }

  interface AggregateSet extends Aggregate {
    @Override
    Set<Model> getInnerModels();
  }

  static class AggregateHashSet implements AggregateSet {
    private final Set<Model> innerModels = newHashSet();

   @Override
   public Set<Model> getInnerModels() {
     return innerModels;
   }
  }
```

The failure is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable over [<TestTracker$Model@4df50bcc>, <TestTracker$Model@6b26e945>] in any order
     but: Not matched: <TestTracker$AggregateHashSet@4690b489>
```

The changes I obtain from the second commit are

```
[NewObject{ new object: TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/86f2152a7afb26768aa24750735c8e4c }, NewObject{ new object: TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/b3d3dfd282c37280661e3e5963cac4ba }, SetChange{ 'innerModels' collection changes :
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/446f556711adf764944f1f7e10601cff' removed
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/86f2152a7afb26768aa24750735c8e4c' added
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/b3d3dfd282c37280661e3e5963cac4ba' added }]
[NewObject{ new object: TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/86f2152a7afb26768aa24750735c8e4c }, NewObject{ new object: TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/b3d3dfd282c37280661e3e5963cac4ba }, SetChange{ 'innerModels' collection changes :
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/446f556711adf764944f1f7e10601cff' removed
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/86f2152a7afb26768aa24750735c8e4c' added
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/b3d3dfd282c37280661e3e5963cac4ba' added }]
[NewObject{ new object: TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/86f2152a7afb26768aa24750735c8e4c }, NewObject{ new object: TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/b3d3dfd282c37280661e3e5963cac4ba }, SetChange{ 'innerModels' collection changes :
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/446f556711adf764944f1f7e10601cff' removed
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/86f2152a7afb26768aa24750735c8e4c' added
  . 'TestTracker$AggregateHashSet/#innerModels/b3d3dfd282c37280661e3e5963cac4ba' added }]
```

However, no new object is added/removed from the collection between the first and the second commit

If I replace `AggregateHashSet` with `AggregateModelArrayList`

```
  static class AggregateModelArrayList implements AggregateList {

    private final List<Model> innerModels = newArrayList();


    @Override
    public List<Model> getInnerModels() {
      return innerModels;
    }

  }
```

The test passes. The reported changes are (as I was expecting)

```
[ValueChange{ 'innerModels/0.property' changed from '' to 'bob' }, ValueChange{ 'innerModels/1.property' changed from '' to 'bab' }]
```

What am I missing?

E2A: Using Javers 3.10.2

Comment: Hi Luigi, Im not sure what is your question

Comment: The question is why am I getting the expected changes only when I use lists and I don’t when I use sets? In other words why doesn’t my test pass?

Answer (score 0):

When you are storing ValueObjects in Sets, JaVers generates identifiers for them. These identifiers are based on hash from toString. So if you change the property on an object, it gets the new identifier. you can see these identifiers on your changes printing. Lists works differently, identifiers are based on list indices. My advice is , if you want to compare Sets, try to map items class as Value or Entity